# I want to know who were the soldiers that had that job

Tags: grammar

It was said recently that Donald Trump had said the above mentioned comment.
Is it grammatically correct?
It seems to me that the correct sentence is:
"I want to know who the soldiers that had that job were".

Comment: Trump is correct. I think you could say *I want to know the soldiers ...*

Comment: Your correction is good and probably an improvement all things considered, but Trump's phrasing is fine. You can certainly imagine a : in there, 'I want to know: who were the soldiers that had that job'. It's very rarely fruitful to take apart what people say off the cuff in a live conversation, especially if they're under any sort of pressure, because obviously you trail off, you think of something else, you add an aside, you stumble over your words. Clearly this wouldn't apply to something like 'I wants to know' or 'I want know' or something like that, but still

Answer (score 1):

Trump's phrasing is correct and understandable.

He was probably trying to place emphasis on the soldiers and show he had some sort of personal connection/interest (politicians like to do that sort of thing)

> who were the soldiers that had that job

he could have also said

> who the soldiers were that had that job